# Calculate largest power of 2 smaller than n

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to do this operation using bit manipulation in C.

```
From a number n, substract the largest power of 2 smaller than n. 

For example:
6 - 4 = 2
11 - 8 = 3
```

My approach is:

```
next2power = nextHighestPowerOf2(n)
previous2power = next2power >> 1;
result = n - previous2power;
```

I've used following hack from [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://www.graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2) in `nextHighestPowerOf2()`.

```
v--;
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
v |= v >> 32;
v++;
```

The problem with this is `next2power` overflows  even when I use `unsigned long long`. `n` is of the order of `2^64`. So this approach isn't working for me.

These two alternate approaches can work here:

1. By flipping the leading `1` to `0`.
2. Somehow calculate highest power of 2 smaller than `n` without overflowing and then subtracting it from `n`

But I couldn't think of any solution. Does anyone know some other way of achieving this?

Comment: Have you head of logarithms. A Scottish guy that lived around my neck of the woods invented them.

Comment: recommendation: Since we're talking about problems with integers of a discrete size, say "..when I use `uint64_t`…" instead of `unsigned long long` (there might be platforms where the latter is e.g. 32 or 128bit)

Comment: @MarcusMüller the standard requires that an `unsigned long long` can hold at least the value `18446744073709551616`, which means it is required to have at least 64bit.

Comment: @mch: I'm surprised; where does ANSI-C say that?

Comment: @mch note that OP doesn't say he's using C99, where that would be specified.

Comment: @harold: ask over at https://twitter.com/StackStatus

Comment: @MarcusMüller there was no `unsigned long long` in C89. The first standard, which has `unsigned long long` (C99) required 64bit for it. So if you use `unsigned long long` with C89, it is an compiler extension.

Comment: @mch your insight is deeper than mine :) Still, and this might be a very personal opinion, people who actually want to use a 64 bit unsigned integer number type should go for `uint64_t`, not `unsigned long long`. If you just want an integer that spans (at least) the range of C99's `unsigned long long`, ok, go for it, but don't complain if bit twiddling tricks don't work on future machines. Here, OP (and many of the answers) build on an assumption about the actual bit length of the variable, and hence should use a type that specifies the length.

Comment: `gcc` version is 5.3.1 and the number I'm trying to solve for is `7597026128958891522`

Comment: Add your "print the result" code, too!

Comment: I think the error was in printing, I was using `lld` instead of `llu`.

Comment: ... so you close this question as "due to a simple typo", or you add an answer of your own, explaining where to pay attention. Or you accept my answer which shows exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might just be making a mistake when entering, or printing your values; the code in your question works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        unsigned long long input, v;

        input = 7597026128958891522ULL;
        v = input;
        v--;
        v |= v >> 1;
        v |= v >> 2;
        v |= v >> 4;
        v |= v >> 8;
        v |= v >> 16; 
        v |= v >> 32; 
        v++;
        v= v>>1;
        printf("Input %llu, next lower power of 2 %llu\n", input, v); 
}
```

yielding

```
Input 7597026128958891522, next lower power of 2 4611686018427387904
```

Comment: But it wouldn't work if the next lower pot would be the top bit

Comment: @harold looping from `input=0` to `16`:
`In 0, next low. 2^p 0
In 1, next low. 2^p 0
In 2, next low. 2^p 1
In 3, next low. 2^p 2
In 4, next low. 2^p 2
In 5, next low. 2^p 4
In 6, next low. 2^p 4
In 7, next low. 2^p 4
In 8, next low. 2^p 4
In 9, next low. 2^p 8
In 10, next low. 2^p 8
In 11, next low. 2^p 8
In 12, next low. 2^p 8
In 13, next low. 2^p 8
In 14, next low. 2^p 8
In 15, next low. 2^p 8
In 16, next low. 2^p 8`

Comment: so yes, that is a case one should consider; "next smaller" is not "next smaller or equal".

Comment: No I mean the actual top bit, because of the `v = v >> 1` it can never result in having the top bit set, but that may be the next pot

Comment: comment out the n-- at the beginning for largest power of two less than OR equal

Answer (score 3):

This should solve your problem

```
unsigned long long int res = n - 1ULL<<( (int)log2(n-1) );
```

Of course you must put special conditions when n<=1

Comment: `log2` is a method that takes `double`; `unsigned long long` might or might not fit into a double (on most platforms, double`s overall range is significantly smaller than `unsigned long long`'s.

Comment: ah, with your edit it's even clearer this is unsuitable for numbers that don't fit in `int`

Comment: @MarcusMüller What are you talking about ? `double` has a much larger range than `unsigned long long`

Comment: even with `log2l` (which is the log2 variant for `long double`), the range of `unsigned long long` might exceed the range of `long double`, so no matter how we put this, it doesn't solve OP problem.

Comment: No, Akshay, that's simply not true.

Comment: There's no standardized relation between the range of `double` and `unsigned long long`; these types are unrelated.

Comment: @MarcusMüller unsigned long long ranges form `0` to `2^64 -1` whereas double ranges from `2.3E-308` to `1.7E+308`

Comment: On **your** particular machine. Not universally. There's machines where single precision float is < 32 bit, for example.

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya: no, double is *not* inherently 64 bit. That's simply not true. It is true for machines where that is the case, which is most compilers on most PCs, but for example on Itaniums, double can be a 80 bit floating point number.

Comment: and there's a whole bunch of processors that don't use IEEE754 floating point numbers at all. Still, the compilers for those use `float` and `double`. There's nothing you can assume about how these floating point numbers work internally.

Comment: Even when it works, it's probably going to be scary slow

Comment: +1 for good math solution. No matter whether you use standard double function log2 or you define your own logarithm on long long. BTW, I think that C standard specifies that the maximum representable finite floating-point number must be at least 1E37.

Comment: @harold This runs in O(1) time, how can it be slow ?

Comment: The input has a constant size so that's no great achievement. Computing a floating point logarithm is a lot of work, taking many elementary operations. Most of it is completely pointless for this use too, the fractional part that it worked so hard on is immediately truncated away.

Comment: @harold the cast to float would actually be the interesting operation here; now, that's a relatively fast operation on many CPUs, and if you took a bit of care with respect to the values you put through that, a simple mask extracting the exponent bits might be a solution. Again, that is **extremely** machine specific.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 64 bits int. You need to add a v |= v >> 32 to copy into the lower 32 bits.

Comment: You, unlike OP, have understood what the bit twiddling hack does :)

Comment: yes, I've added `v |= v >> 32` in my code. The problem is that `nextHighestPowerOf2()` returns a negative value.

Comment: Use the proper type then.

Comment: @harold I'm using `unsigned long long` for storing all the numbers in my code. Otherwise even the number won't fit, let alone the next higher power of two. What type should I use? I'm not well-versed in C.

Comment: There's no way for an unsigned number to ever be negative. Maybe you printed it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

While `n` is not a power of two, keep turning off the least significat bit set on. You can do the latter operation with `n &= (n-1);` (think about it).

Expressed in C99:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int n) {
    while (n & (n-1)) { // n is *not* a power of two
        n &= (n-1);
    }

    return n;
}

int main() {
    for (int n = 1; n < 130; ++n) {
        printf("%d : %d\n", n, f(n));
    }
}
```

The beauty of this is that the running time is proportional to the number of bits set on.

Sample output:

```
blazs@blazs:/tmp$ ./x
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 2
4 : 4
5 : 4
6 : 4
7 : 4
8 : 8
9 : 8
10 : 8
11 : 8
12 : 8
13 : 8
14 : 8
15 : 8
16 : 16
17 : 16
18 : 16
19 : 16
20 : 16
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `n &= n - 1`? `n &= ~(n -1)` makes it isolate the lowest set bit, which is the opposite of the description (and useless in a loop)

Comment: @blazs : Please test your answer before posting. I'm not fond of downvoting, I rather suggest you run it, see what's wrong and fix it yourself: `int main()
{
int n;
for(int i = 0; i < 129; i++)
     printf("The largest power of 2 smaller than %d is %d\n", i, f(i));
return 0;
}`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected the code, it now works---yes, it should indeed be `n &= (n-1)`. I was in a hurry when writing the post. :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the highest set bit almost always works, and that is easy:

```
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
v |= v >> 32;  // you need this line for 64bit numbers
v &= ~(v >> 1);
```

But not always. If `n` is already a power of two, its highest set bit is equal to itself, not less than. So put that `v--` at the beginning back.

FWIW, taking the log and shifting is likely faster, as long as you have a proper built-in way to take an integer log (`bsr` or equivalent). FP log would likely be a disaster.

ps: none of this was tested.

Comment: That's why the bit hack has the v-- in the beginning, to resolve the "v being already a power of 2" by bumping down into the next power tier.